# Mandatory volunteer contribution to maintain membership status. How would you implement?

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, status

Volunteer-based cooperatives often have requirements for its members to maintain an 'Active' status in order to be eligible to vote in meetings or elections.

For example, my cooperative requires:

A) at least 24 hours of volunteer service in the financial year when applying for membership.

B) at least 24 hours of volunteer service in subsequent financial years to maintain an 'Active' status.

Typically, individuals declare on a paper form their annual volunteer contribution. It would be ideal to scan/upload PDF documents into CiviCRM annually and simply tick a checkbox that the member has complied with the requirement of active membership.

I can see multiple ways to implement this but does anyone with CiviCRM experience have a suggestion on how they would implement this?

Which Module would you use or customise?

Cheers,

Troy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use the CiviRules extension for this (to be found here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules with documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/ ) and then:

1. set up an activity for uploading the document
2. set up a CiviRule with trigger new activity, condition on activity type and status (and possibly attachment) and action tag the contact as an active member.